# How to have different codebase and assets for different flavor in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have two Android app which uses same code base. In Android native, i can use the different resource folder for each android flavor. Also i can use gradle property of sourceSets to define source and resource folder for flavors. This helps to minimize the apk size.

How can achieve the same in flutter?

I am able to create the different flavor in flutter but the flutter codebase and assests would be common for all flavors.

Comment: check out this - https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i have already checked it. It just enable to have different flavor but doesn't have anything on having different codebase and assests in flutter code.